# 'SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'batch_classify' in NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, nltk

I'm trying to classify datas using NLTK's SklearnClassifier and BernoulliNB. This is some code:

```
train = posFeatures[174:]+negFeatures[174:]+neuFeatures[174:]
devtest = posFeatures[124:174]+negFeatures[124:174]+neuFeatures[124:174]
test = posFeatures[:124]+negFeatures[:124]+neuFeatures[:124]
dev, tag_dev = zip(*devtest)
def score(classifier):
    classifier = SklearnClassifier(classifier)
    classifier.train(train)
    pred = classifier.batch_classify(dev)
    return accuracy_score(tag_dev,pred)
print('BernoulliNB  accuracy is %f'%score(BernoulliNB()) )
```

and then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pycharm/quanbu.py", line 53, in <module>
    print('BernoulliNB  accuracy is %f'%score(BernoulliNB()) )
  File "G:/pycharm/quanbu.py", line 51, in score
    pred = classifier.batch_classify(dev)
AttributeError: 'SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'batch_classify'
```

I'm using python3.5.2,nltk3.2.1,scikit-learn 0.18.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0

Comment: Better yet, since you're just getting started and have no code to port yet: Find the current version of whatever documentation you need.

Comment: Thanks guys,i have resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You've been looking at obsolete documentation. With nltk 3 the name was changed to `classify_many()`. (Similarly in other modules, `batch_pos_tag()` and `batch_parse()` were changed to `pos_tag_sents()` and `parse_sents()` respectively.)